# How to check IP range in nginx location?

Tags: nginx, ip

I have nginx.conf and need to check the client request IP `$remote_addr` in IPs range or not?
My IP range means `123.132.123.15` to `123.132.123.50` (15 - 50). And valid IPs need include some specific IPs. Any solution without input 36 IP addresses in the list. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that (for example) using `ranges` and the [nginx geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html).

This is the example from the page:

> Example with ranges:
>
> ```
> geo $country {
>     ranges;
>     default                   ZZ;
>     127.0.0.0-127.0.0.0       US;
>     127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1       RU;
>     127.0.0.1-127.0.0.255     US;
>     10.1.0.0-10.1.255.255     RU;
>     192.168.1.0-192.168.1.255 UK;
> }
> ```

Alternatively you can calculate the CIDR notation of your range using any calculator (or mentally, if you're so inclined) and block them using the nginx [http access module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html).

For your example this would look something like this:

```
location /whatever {
    deny  123.132.123.15/32
    deny  123.132.123.16/28
    deny  123.132.123.32/28
    deny  123.132.123.48/31
    deny  123.132.123.50/32;
    allow all;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the second example?

Comment: I calculated your given IP range using a CIDR calculator and inserted them into the deny rules. These 5 CIDR cover all 36 IPs of your range. As far as I know the http access module doesn't support the range notation.